# Text shown by uib-tooltip on a single line

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Having the following code:

```
  <i ng-if="!$ctrl.aggregated"
     ng-class="!$ctrl.mainObj[item.name].hidden ? 'fa fa-check-square':'fa fa-square consumption-item__disabled'"
     ng-style="{'color': item.color}"
     ng-click="$ctrl.onItemClicked(item)"></i>
    {{item.name}}
    <i ng-if="!$ctrl.aggregated && $ctrl.multi" 
       class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-bullseye-position"
       ng-click="$ctrl.onFocusClicked(item)"
       uib-tooltip="this is my text"></i>
</div>
```

There is a tooltip at the end: `uib-tooltip="this is my text"` which is shown in two lines:

[image: shown tooltip]

Is there a way to make it appear on one line the whole text?

Comment: try `tooltip-placement="top"` (or `"top-right"`)

Comment: I added it inside the <i> tag but has no effect

Comment: you can add custom CSS with `tooltip-class="customClass"`, in CSS class you can write `white-space: nowrap;`. The problem is that the tooltip has a fixed max width

Comment: for other options see what's available in the api: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#tooltip (but I would go with the custom class)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey the second approach works well, thanks!